# Concurrent request in django

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Concurrent request to Django API from vue returns the response from the last request for both.

Here is my snippet from vue component

```
methods:{
    users(){
          axios.get('users').then((response) => {
               this.sers = response.data;
             }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
             });
    },
    new_users(){
        axios.get('users', {
               params: {type:'new'},
             }).then((response) => {
               this.new_users = response.data;
             }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
             });
     }
},
mounted(){ 
 this.users();
 this.new_users();  

}
```

and my python snippet from the Django view

```
def list_objects(request):
    if 'type' in request.GET and request.GET['type'] =='new' :
        #return new users
    else:
        #return users
```

The problem is the new_users() and users() methods respond with new users data(the one which called last, if we call the users() method last both methods get users data )

Comment: try to use not `request.GET` but `request.query_params` (but it also not good decision - google django-filters library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Django development server. When I switch to [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) all problems gone and now working as expected.